# How to fit a data table (CSV file) with a given custom fitting function and plot it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, datatable, data-fitting

I have a given data table:

```
t in [s] s_1 in [m]

0       -0,25

0,1      0,2435

0,2     -0,2213
```

...

which has to be fitted by the model `A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)`.
After the fit I have to determine A, omega_0 and phi.

I tried to code it in matlab, but unfortunately the code isn't working and the plot doesn't show.

In the following I show you my current code (the data table is already imported in matlab):

```
readtable('ungedaempft.csv','NumHeaderLines',1);  % skips the first row of data

% cos is a non linear function

x = linspace(-1000,1000);  
y = linspace(-1000,1000);
myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent="s_1",independent="t",coefficients=["A" "omega_0" "phi"]);

myfit = fit(x',y',myfittype);
plot(myfit,x,y);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: " the code isn't working" this can mean that it errors, that it produces an unwanted result or that your computer is set on fire. Can you clarify what you mean exactly